# How to append error message to form.non_field_errors in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form with several fields. I have separate validation checks for each field, done via the forms validation. I however also need to check if few fields are filled in before redirecting the user to a different view. I was hoping I could somehow append the error to forms.non_field_errors as it is not for a particular field , but I am not sure what the right syntax for this would be. I have checked online and found..

```
form.errors['__all__'] = form.error_class(["error msg"])
```

This displays the error message, but it seems to mess up the other pages as well and displyas the error message if I click on anything else.

I tried

```
form._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = form.error_class()
```

This causes a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setdefault' error for me.

I have tried

```
form.non_field_errors().append("Please complete your profile in order to access the content.")
```

This doesn't seem to do anything and I cant see the error message on the view.

What would be the best way to do this? Ideally I dont' want to do it in the form's clean method. I feel like I should be able to append an error to the form in the view.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. **Call full_clean()**, this should initialize `form._errors`. This step is critical, if you don't do it, it won't work.
2. **Make the error list**, it takes a list of messages, instanciate it as such: `error_list = form.error_class(['your error messages'])`
3. **Assign the error list to NON_FIELD_ERRORS**, you have to import `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` from `django.forms.forms`, then assign as such: `form._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = error_list`

Here is a demonstration from a shell:

```
In [1]: from bet.forms import BetForm

In [2]: from django.forms.forms import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

In [3]: form = BetForm()

In [4]: form.full_clean()

In [5]: form._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = form.error_class(['your error messages'])

In [6]: form.non_field_errors()
Out[6]: [u'your error messages']
```

Comment: I know I can do it in the Form.clean() method. However I would prefer to do it in the view and just append an error to the form.errors list, is this possible at all?

Comment: Well yes it's possible my answer proves it :)

Comment: Thanks jpic for your detailed answer. I will try this code out and get back. Sorry for the late response, I have been away on vacation.

Comment: As an FYI to others looking at this answer: this works well in Django 1.5.

Comment: The original question was regarding appending an error to the list (not completely replacing the list). The author further reiterated this in the first reply to this question, and was apparently ignored.

This answer does not actually solve the question at all, as it will scrub all existing non-field errors from the form when it paves over them.

Comment: It's true that the answer focuses more on Django's API rather than "how to use python lists" because the question author seemed to know how to use lists, and seemed to struggle rather with Django's API. While it would have been possible to make the answer twice longer by lecturing about Python list usage, I did judge it un-necessary as you have noticed. It's cool that this answer (POC included) was helpful to the Angela (hence the third comment). BTW, welcome to StackOverflow ! Feel free to contribute your own answers or to improve existing answers. Thanks in advance for your contribution.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit out-dated but i recently ran into the same question and wanted to shed some further light on this for future readers.

1. As of Django 1.6+ the errors dictionary is stored as form.errors and not form._errors
2. If you instantiate form.is_valid(), it is the equivalent of running full_clean()
3. NON_FIELD_ERRORS isn't necessary to import, you can simply refer to its default dictionary key of `__all__`

Example:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.errors['__all__'] = form.error_class(['Your Error Here!'])
```

Comment: Well in general it's better to use defined constants, ie. `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` over its value `__all__`. Also, as far as I understand, the point of setting non field errors **before** calling `is_valid()` is to be able to actually influence the result of the `is_valid()`.

Comment: I agree with the NON_FIELD_ERRORS constant part, i just wanted to point out an alternative. 

As for the setting non-field-errors, what i was trying to say is that non-field-errors isn't instantiated unless is_valid() or full_clean() is called at all. If you try accession before running either method you'll get a KeyError. Unless what you were trying to say is that one should run full_clean() before running is_valid()?

Comment: This is full of misinformation:  form.errors is a property that accesses the internal list form._errors.  And it is good practice to use NON_FIELD_ERRORS as a constant since the developers may one day suddenly decide that the constant should be equivalent to the string "_la_le_loo_".  That's why we have constants in languages--so we can abstract and maintain our code more easily.  Also, form.is_valid() is not the equivalent of running full_clean().  is_valid() calls form.errors, which calls full_clean to populate the _errors dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

On form there is method add_error.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form) :

    def clean(self) :
        self.add_error(None, "The __all__ error message")
        return super().clean()
```

The first param of `add_error()` function is about the refered fields.
If the field is `None` the `add_error()` function will considere that the error is a `form_error`.

The `clean()` method is a hook called by `_clean_form()`.
Then the `_clean_form()` function is called by `full_clean()`. See more: [full_clean() source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/61c2d58d017874283921537f8ff1fe31b7652a63/django/forms/forms.py#L361)

Answer (score -1):

`self._errors.setdefault('__all__', ErrorList()).extend([""])`

Comment: You should explain your answers here, not just drop in a random code snippet