# How to show database errors to user in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql, exception, django-admin

Background: my Django application sits onto top of a pre-existing Postgresql database.  This database has a very complex network of triggers and constraints.

Question: In the Django Admin, if a user causes a DatabaseError on save, I would like to show the error back to them in a user friendly format, similar to the builtin forms.ValidationError.

Example (this doesn't work, it causes a 500):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    try:
        obj.save()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        raise forms.ValidationError(e)
```

Expected Result:

Shown to user in Admin, "`Database Error: ID 58574 - Price is outside customers requested range.  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`."

Comment: `Price is outside customers requested range` : Can you show the models (and the constraint you have specified)

Comment: I'm looking for something more generic that works for any model/constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@twil -- Thanks for your help.  You put me on the right track.  Really appreciate your help.   However, the solution didn't work out of box.  Didn't actually show errors in my test case or work with change_view.  Here's want I ended up working with.

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from django.db import DatabaseError, IntegrityError
from django.contrib import messages


class ShowValidationAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            return super(ShowValidationAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
        except (IntegrityError, DatabaseError) as e:

            request.method = 'GET'
            messages.error(request, e.message)
            return super(ShowValidationAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            return super(ShowValidationAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
        except (IntegrityError, DatabaseError) as e:

            request.method = 'GET'
            messages.error(request, e.message)
            return super(ShowValidationAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Note: That this version also seems to work cross version (django 1.3 - 1.6).  Let me know if anyone has a better approach. I'll wait to award bounty.

Comment: Your solution is shorter but less user friendly because you are loosing changes with `request.method = 'GET'`. User will have to refill all the necessary fields and not only fix the wrong ones.

Answer (score 7):

You need to slightly change your logic if possible. What you need is custom [`AdminModel.form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form). All validation should be done there. See the note for [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods):

> ModelAdmin.save_model() and ModelAdmin.delete_model() must save/delete
>   the object, they are not for veto purposes, rather they allow you to
>   perform extra operations.

But if your circumstances are so that you can't do all validation inside the form I'd subclass `ModelAdmin` and override [`def add_view()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1098), [`def change_view()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1186) and [`def changelist_view()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1278) like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import helpers
from django.contrib.admin.options import csrf_protect_m, IS_POPUP_VAR
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

# for nonfield errors to show correctly
from django.forms.forms import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

from .models import TestModel


class TestModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        raise Exception('test exception')

    @csrf_protect_m
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            return super(TestModelAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        # mimic parent class on error

        model = self.model
        opts = model._meta

        ModelForm = self.get_form(request)
        formsets = []
        inline_instances = self.get_inline_instances(request, None)
        form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.is_valid()

        # make faked nonfield error
        # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598247/how-to-append-error-message-to-form-non-field-errors-in-django
        form._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = form.error_class([e.message])

        # We may handle exception here (just to save indentation)
        adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(form, list(self.get_fieldsets(request)),
            self.get_prepopulated_fields(request),
            self.get_readonly_fields(request),
            model_admin=self)
        media = self.media + adminForm.media

        inline_admin_formsets = []
        for inline, formset in zip(inline_instances, formsets):
            fieldsets = list(inline.get_fieldsets(request))
            readonly = list(inline.get_readonly_fields(request))
            prepopulated = dict(inline.get_prepopulated_fields(request))
            inline_admin_formset = helpers.InlineAdminFormSet(inline, formset,
                fieldsets, prepopulated, readonly, model_admin=self)
            inline_admin_formsets.append(inline_admin_formset)
            media = media + inline_admin_formset.media

        context = {
            'title': _('Add %s') % force_text(opts.verbose_name),
            'adminform': adminForm,
            'is_popup': IS_POPUP_VAR in request.REQUEST,
            'media': media,
            'inline_admin_formsets': inline_admin_formsets,
            'errors': helpers.AdminErrorList(form, formsets),
            'app_label': opts.app_label,
            'preserved_filters': self.get_preserved_filters(request),
        }
        context.update(extra_context or {})
        return self.render_change_form(request, context, form_url=form_url, add=True)

admin.site.register(TestModel, TestModelAdmin)
```

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class TestModel(models.Model):

    text = models.TextField()
```

You see, there's no easy way of hooking inside `save_model()` so you'll have to copy-paste part of form preparation code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        try:
            obj.save()
        except DatabaseError as e:
            raise ValidationError(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but nobody mentioned [ModelAdmin.message_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.message_user) yet, which also uses the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/).

For example:

```py
from django.contrib import admin, messages

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    
    def save_model(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super().save_model(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except DatabaseError as e:
            messages.set_level(request=request, level=messages.ERROR)            
            self.message_user(request=request, message=e, level=messages.ERROR)
```

This would show your message as follows (assuming that's the error string in `e`):

[image: error message]

The `set_level` call suppresses the default success message. Also see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25449233) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3712814).

Answer (score 0):

In [save_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), you can handle [DatabaseError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/exceptions/#django.db.DatabaseError) exception separately and differently for adding or changing an object as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): # Here
        last_part_of_path = request.path.split('/')[-2]

        if last_part_of_path == "add":
            try: # ↓ I intentionally raise an exception
                raise DatabaseError("Add Error")
                obj.save()
            except DatabaseError as e:
                messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
                messages.error(request, e)

        if last_part_of_path == "change":
            try: # ↓ I intentionally raise an exception
                raise DatabaseError("Change Error")
                obj.save()
            except DatabaseError as e:
                messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
                messages.error(request, e)
```